# DATATABLE NO MUESTRA BOTONES

Tags: c#, ajax, bootstrap, mvc, datatables

ESTOY UTILIZANDO DATATABLE PARA MI DISEÑO  PERO TENGO UN PROBLEMA CON LOS BOTONES DE EXPORTACION , NO  SE VISUALIZAN ,

MI  JS ES

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#listaDocumentos').DataTable();

});

var table = $('#listaDocumentos').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
    ],
    language: {
        "decimal": "",
        "emptyTable": "No hay información",
        "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Documentos",
        "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Documentos",
        "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
        "infoPostFix": "",
        "thousands": ",",
        "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Documentos",
        "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "processing": "Procesando...",
        "search": "Buscar:",
        "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
        "paginate": {
            "first": "Primero",
            "last": "Ultimo",
            "next": "Siguiente",
            "previous": "Anterior"
        }
    }
});
```

MI TABLA ES

```
<table id="listaDocumentos" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Donna Snider</td>
            <td>Customer Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$112,000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Y MIS LINK SON

> ```
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.18/js/datatables.min.js"></script> <link href="~/Content/DataTables-1.10.18/css/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
> ```

Y ESTE ES EL RESULTADO PERO NO ME MUESTRA LOS BOTONES PARA EXPORTAR 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Tienes librerias de mas.  No tienes que incluir dos veces jquery ni datatables.

```js
var table = $('#listaDocumentos').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
    ],
    language: {
        "decimal": "",
        "emptyTable": "No hay información",
        "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Documentos",
        "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Documentos",
        "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
        "infoPostFix": "",
        "thousands": ",",
        "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Documentos",
        "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "processing": "Procesando...",
        "search": "Buscar:",
        "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
        "paginate": {
            "first": "Primero",
            "last": "Ultimo",
            "next": "Siguiente",
            "previous": "Anterior"
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"> <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

<table id="listaDocumentos" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Donna Snider</td>
            <td>Customer Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$112,000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te faltan varias comillas en los parámetros de Datatables. Puedes también hacer uso de los botones exportar en html5, pongo tu script con las comillas faltantes y los botones html5

Añade a tus Script este de los botones html5 y asi no es necesario Flash para los botones antiguos:

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js">
```

Y tu script correcto:

```
var table = $('#listaDocumentos').DataTable({
    "dom": 'Bfrtip',
    "buttons": [
            'pageLength',
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ],
    "lengthMenu": [
            [ 10, 25, 50, -1 ],
            [ '10 Resultados', '25 Resultados', '50 Resultados', 'Motrar Todos' ]
        ],
    "buttons": {
        "pageLength": {
            _: "Mostrar %d Registros"
        }
    },
    "language": {
        "decimal": "",
        "emptyTable": "No hay información",
        "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Documentos",
        "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Documentos",
        "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
        "infoPostFix": "",
        "thousands": ",",
        "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Documentos",
        "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "processing": "Procesando...",
        "search": "Buscar:",
        "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
        "paginate": {
            "first": "Primero",
            "last": "Ultimo",
            "next": "Siguiente",
            "previous": "Anterior"
        }
    }
});
```